# How method java.util.Collections#copy should look in kotlin?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, intellij-idea

Many guids in which try to explain differences between `? extend T` and `? super T` use as example method `java.util.Collections#copy`

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
}
```

How this method should look in kotlin? 
If i try to copy and past this method in Kotlin class and convert to kotlin by IntelliJ Idea when this method look like

```
fun <T> copy(dest: List<in T?>?, src: List<T?>?) {}
```

But this code not compiled.

Comment: Good to refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846025/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-kotlin/52907983

Comment: @user Er yes, you can, search for "use-site variance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin List are not mutable. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492780/kotlin-generics-declaration-site-variance-in-t-construction)

```
fun <T> copy(
    dest: MutableList<in T>,
    src: List<T>
) {
}
```